# How can I add vertical spacing between colored boxes, created using a width and padding in CSS?

Tags: html, css

So I'm pretty new to WebDev so bare with me here: I've created a colored square with a width of 70%, height of 0 and a padding of 70%. I have done that multiple times to create a box grid on the website. There is a `h2` inside of that box with the following styling:

```css
  color: $white;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3%;
  margin-left: -0.5%;
```

The box itself has the following styling:

```css
  background-color: $primary;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
```

Now these boxes lineup directly with each other height wise (I'm using bootstrap for three boxes per row), how would I add a space between each box vertically?

I've tried using a margin but that messes with the h2 and does not let me bring it down anymore and padding does not seem to do anything.

My goal is to have a gap between each box vertically in which I would like to add a single line p tag.

Here is the full source code: HTML:

```css
.box-1-1 {
  background-color: $primary;
  width: 70%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 70%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha512-3dZ9wIrMMij8rOH7X3kLfXAzwtcHpuYpEgQg1OA4QAob1e81H8ntUQmQm3pBudqIoySO5j0tHN4ENzA6+n2r4w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="col-4">
  <div class="box-1-1">
    <h2 class="boxes">RDA EXPO</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is one box, ive done this 12 times with three boxes per row

Comment: Please also include your HTML so as to make a [mre].

Comment: I'm not following.  If you plan to put an element in the space between the boxes, then how does that not itself produce the wanted gap?

Comment: Please provide your HTML code

Comment: please provide a working snippet, include bootstrap

Comment: Since you're creating a grid you may want to [learn how to use `display:grid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) (also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout and  https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-use-css-grid-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend looking at grid for a lot of your layouts.

```
div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
}
```

I replaced your code with this for css, and it puts a box around both divs and places them both next to each other. I do not think what you are after is empty p tags to create space. What you want to do is learn how to work with css properties to create the layouts you want. Old school way is to use float: left. New school way is to use display: flex. Newest school way is to use display: grid. All of these are highly needed to be learned.

1. [Floats](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/)
2. [Flexbox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=phWxA89Dy94)
3. [Grid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rg7Fvvl3taU&t=3s)
4. [All three](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R7gqJkdc5dM)

Knowing how these three layout tools work on a basic level will immensely help your css knowledge.
In addition,

> how would I add a space between each box vertically?

If you use grid or flex, there are gap properties you can use to cause the items to put space between elements, both vertically and horizontally. Using floats is a little harder, but there are ways to [vertically position](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/18/vertically-center-floated-elements-flexbox/) [those too](https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/center-vertically-inside-float).
Good luck.